# Sub class variable is not hiding the variable in super class

Tags: java, class, member-hiding

I just learned that if there are two variables, one in super class and one in sub class which share the same name the value assigned to the variable in the subclass will hide the value  of the variable in super class. I have written a program to check that out, but the out put is clearly showing that any hiding process is not happening or is it really happening? if the sub class hides the variable in super class the value of "A.a" and "B.a" should be 25 right? help me out please.

Note: I am new to this java programming. explain your answer in detail please. thank you

here is the code

```
public class Super {
  int a;

  Super(int x) {
    a = x;
  }

}

class something extends Super {
  int a;

  something(int x, int y) {
    super(x);
    a = y;
  }
}

class mainclass {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Super A = new Super(10);
    something B = new something(10, 25);

    System.out.println("The value of a in super class is" + A.a);
    System.out.println("The value of a in sub class is" + B.a);
  }
}
```

output is here:

```
The value of a in super class is10
The value of a in sub class is25
```

Comment: You might want to use less confusing names next time. You could call the sub class `SubClass` instead of `something`, and you should have used lower case names for the instances (instead of A and B).

Comment: Try another round with getters in your classes. A.getSuperA() and B.getSuperA() and B.getSubA().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A.a` shouldn't return 25, since the type of `A` is the super type `Super`, and there's no hiding. That's why `A.a` returns 10.

Only in `B.a` there's hiding of `a` (since B is of type `something` which extends `Super` and hides member `a`), which is why it returns 25.

Comment: But he's not getting 10; he's getting 25.

Comment: the way you phrase it seems really unclear to me. The line "in B.a ... you get 10" sounds like it's saying the opposite of what's true.

Comment: I am reading a topic about how to use "super" keyword. the author of the book I am reading says you can use "super keyword" when the sub class variable hides the super class variable. so when actually the sub class hides the super class variable? in the program I have written is it hiding or is it not? your answer is confusing. sorry I am new.

Comment: @Srimanth Yes, in your program, the sub class `something` hides the super class variable.

Comment: @Eran If it is hiding then why it is showing "10". the value 10 should be hidden so the value should be 25 for both A.a and B.a?

Comment: @Srimanth 10 is printed for `A.a`. A is of type Super. Therefore for A there is no hiding. Only for B, whose type is the sub class, the member `a` hides the member `a` of the super class.

Comment: @Srimanth: you can still access the hidden variable by using `((Super)B).a`. But the keyword `super` is not applicable here as only *within* the class `something` you can access members inherited from class `Super` using the `super` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tha "a" in the subclass hides the "a" in the super class. Thats why you assign the "a"  in the sub class in the constructor of something.